# Is the Artillerist artificer's Eldritch Cannon a carryable weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, artificer

In *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, the [Artillerist subclass for the Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Artillerist) gets a feature called [Eldritch Cannon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#EldritchCannon-1138963). When you summon the cannon you can choose to summon it as either a Small object or a Tiny object:

> [you] magically create a Small or Tiny eldritch cannon in an unoccupied space on a horizontal surface within 5 feet of you. A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a Tiny one can be held in one hand.

Does this mean that my character can walk around with a Tiny-size eldritch cannon, carrying and using it as a weapon? Or does it still just sit and move on its own?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rules say the cannon can be held in one hand, but it doesn't say you can use your action to use its ability. So you can have it in your offhand and use your bonus action to use its ability as written and still attack with a weapon or spell with your main hand. But you can't use your action to use its ability again using the Attack action, because its specific description tells you it takes a bonus action to use, and it doesn't involve a weapon attack.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I thought of a way to use your Attack action to use it: as an improvised weapon. It is definitely more viable to just use a weapon you are proficient with, instead of swinging this thing at them, dealing only 1d4 and not being able to add proficiency to hit. But it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

As written, Yes. You can hold the legs of the cannon like a gun and fire it.

You can also drop it at anytime and it will walk on it's own and still fire it.