# Must the Artillerist Artificer's Tiny Eldritch Cannon be carried in their hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, artificer

The Artillerist Artificer has the ability to make Eldritch Cannon(s). The rules for the cannon state that you can make two different sized versions of it:

> you can take an action to magically create a Small or Tiny eldritch cannon in an unoccupied space on a horizontal surface within 5 reet of you. A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a Tiny one can be held in one hand.

**The wording is a little vague. Do the rules mean that the tiny version**:

1. Doesn't occupy a space, therefore *must* be held in the artificer's hand
2. *Can* be held in one hand, unlike the small version, but otherwise functions like the small version with regard to space and movement if it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure if the creature size tag applies, since the cannon isn't a creature, but I think the rules still apply. Can someone smarter than me advise?

Comment: Closely related to this question: [Is the Artillerist artificer's Eldritch Cannon a carryable weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160103/is-the-artillerist-artificers-eldritch-cannon-a-carryable-weapon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You do not need to carry it

Both versions of the cannon must be initially placed in an unoccupied space, so it *must* be true that they can exist without being carried.  Why then, the distinction?  Well, the wording is simply giving each version of the cannon a piece of rules text that is specific to it.

#### A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space (and a Tiny one does not)

A space in which a small cannot resides is considered "occupied."  Effects that require an unoccupied space cannot make use of that area.  It's not clear whether hostile creatures can move through the space, but since the space is "occupied," it's likely that no creature can end its turn in that space.  This cannon might be used as partial cover or to prevent flanking, depending on the situation.

The only thing implied by making this descriptor specific to the Small cannon is that it is not true of the Tiny cannon.  The Tiny cannon *does not* occupy its space, and that space can be used for any other feature that needs it.  It's clear that the space can be moved through by any creature.

#### A Tiny one can be held in one hand (and a Small one cannot)

A Tiny cannon is small enough to hold in only one hand.  You can carry it around while using your other hand for whatever you'd like.

The only thing implied by making this descriptor specific to the Tiny cannon is that it is not true of the Small cannon.  The Small cannon *cannot* be held in one hand, and thus requires two to carry or move.