# Artificer Eldritch Cannon and hands

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

The artificer class in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* allows for the production of an eldritch cannon at 3rd level.

> [you] magically create a Small or Tiny eldritch cannon in an unoccupied space on a horizontal surface within 5 feet of you. A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a Tiny one can be held in one hand.

If a player wants the tiny cannon to 'attach' to their shoulder (I'm fine with the flavour of this...or wrap it's legs around it's wrist etc), am I correct in ruling it still occupies (for lack of a better term) 'hand slot'.

For example:

1. If the artificer has a Sheild in one hand and has this eldritch cannon on their shoulder, then would they no longer have a free hand to perform a spell casting that requires somatic components? Hold tools?
2. Would it be considered "worn or carried" with regards to being able to move with you?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Reopened

Comment: Related, may contain a dupe: [Must the Artillerist Artificer's Tiny Eldritch Cannon be carried in their hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165559/52137), [Can the Artificer Artillerist's tiny-sized Eldritch Cannon that is not held in hand still ride or be carried elsewhere on the body?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163347/52137), [Is the Artillerist artificer's Eldritch Cannon a carryable weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160103/52137)

Comment: @ Rykara, Mostly, especially in the comments to the answer. In summary, is it your interpretation that if it is being worn, rather then specifically carried, your movement is limited to 15 feet? I just don't know if having a shield, bonus action a flame thrower and cast a spell, while gaining benefits of being worn/carried.

Comment: @ Rykara Thanks! FYI cam up with a home brew to make a mount extensions and the cannon can be attached to that, but it takes time so can't just be done in combat. At least they have prepare for a scenario and use resources for it.